# How can we unable to entry if first number is 0. Read Below for the detail :

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can we unable to entry if first number is 0 in textbox. For example :

If anyone enters :

- 000000000     - Do not accept
- 0000001     - accept
- 0000001002     - accept
- 0     - Do not accept

If any one have an idea kindly share to me.

Comment: do you mean last character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer, its a minor task !

```
 int idd = Convert.ToInt16(hour_value.text);
           int p = 0;
    if (idd > p)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp), [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) to convert to number and compare it with zero.

```
if(parseInt(num) > 0)
{
}
```

if it is number and you do not have to convert it to number then you do not need to use parseInt.

```
if(num > 0)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the input string to a number, then:

```
if(inputNumber%10 == 0) {/*run deny code*/} else {/*run accept code*/}
```

Comment: But there is some error on this, when i enters 10 or 1000. Then it not enter the data.

Comment: What does inputNumber%10 return?

Comment: Need more details on the error. Can't help you without details!

Comment: Suppose if i enter : hour_value = 10;

        if (Convert.ToInt32(hour_value) % 10 = 0 {}.  Then it not enter the data. Same in 1000, 100000

Comment: Use Integer.parseInt(String)

Comment: Either way, pretty sure this isn't a problem with my answer.

Comment: But Asp.net doesn't accept this line  Integer.parseInt(String).

Comment: Oh, whoops. I thought this was Java. My bad. Either way, what is the value of `(inputNumber%10)`?

Comment: This works if i enter  multiple zero like 000000000  -- not accepted 10111  --- accept . But when i enter 10 or 100 then it also --- not accepted.

Comment: I'm not asking what causes it to fail - I'm asking you to output the value of (inputNumber%10). Look up modulo division - the answer to this question is correct, as far as I can tell. Unless you edit your post to add source, I can't debug this for you.